# Does IHP support a Ubuntu Server for ARM?

Tags: ihp

Does IHP support a Ubuntu Server for ARM?

https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm

```
Major Operating Systems Supported:
Windows (via Linux Subsystem), macOS, NixOS, Debian, Ubuntu
```

https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/release.html

For Apple M1, there is an open issue.

https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/1113

Answer (score 0):

While Apple M1's are confirmed to be not working, there's no data on the situation on Ubuntu ARM yet.